# JProgressBar positioning to bottom of the window

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jprogressbar

I was trying to position a `JProgressBar` to the bottom of the window's screen. I have tried using `setVerticalAlignment` and `setHorizontalAlignment`. When doing so a syntax error appears.

To make it clear my goal is to put a progress bar at the bottom of the window.

[image: image of frame]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to set the parent container to have a `BorderLayout`, then `panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);` will make the progress bar appear at the bottom.